# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Tags: android

I'm new to android and trying to learn some basic stuff, My problem is if i paste this line `android:layout_gravity="center"` in the default "activity_main.xml" file I'm getting the error in the title but if I delete the line the error disappears!

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        andriod:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        
  
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is simple

Instead of

```
andriod:layout_gravity
```

write

```
android:layout_gravity
```